# How to average over a value range?

Tags: matlab

I want to extract values out from measurement data with matlab.
The data looks like in the figure below, i.e. the green points should represent the average value of the blue data at that Y position:

[image: extract value]

Any ideas how to get a single point for the green points? How could I apply hystersis, or some othe strategy?

Comment: you want to get `1st moment` of a signal, which is `mean`.

Comment: Post a small example of your data variables and the expected result

Comment: Is the range of those green values on x-axis, same as the x-axis range for blue values? If yes, then you just need to take the mean.

Comment: in fact, the blue lines are high-frequency fluctuations. Also, the vectors are rather long. I'll post an update tomorrow